# Change Emacs modes within specific tags

Tags: emacs, tags, emacs23

OK, I know you're going to point me to [EmacsWiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes), but here's the deal. I'd like to use the default Emacs mode for a given file type, and change mode after specific tag, say `<% %>`. By doing such, I can switch the mode inside the tags, and return to default mode when cursor is not inside tags.

And no, I don't need ASP/PHP mode, it just that I find boring `M-x`-ing all the time in order to change the mode. I'm using Emacs 23.2.1 on Arch Linux FWIW. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at mmm-mode: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mmm-mode/ or noweb-mode. [Here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Literate_programming#Multi-mode_support_in_Emacs) are instructions for getting mmm-mode to work with literate Haskell documents. And [here](http://mpastell.com/pweave/emacs.html) is the configuration I use for noweb-mode with literate (rst+python) Python documents.

Comment: I don't like `mmm-mode`, I find it hard to configure, but `noweb-mode` is a great find, especially 'cause I use it for Sweave (R + LaTeX). Thanks!

Comment: The mmm-mode archive also contains the manual in texinfo format so you can convert it also to pdf if you wan't: `texi2pdf mmm.texinfo`

Answer (score 1):

**[nXhtml](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html)**

> nXhtml is an addon to Emacs for editing XHTML, PHP and similar things.

nXhtml comes with [MuMaMo](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MuMaMo) (Multiple <s>Master</s> Major Mode), which I think is a newer version of `mmm-mode`. I use it all the time when editing Django HTML files which combine CSS, JavaScript and Django-aware HTML modes.

Comment: I don't need a plugin for webdev. I used nXhtml for a while, but I'm not using it anymore, and the only way to use MuMaMo is to use nXhtml. So it's a no-no for me...

Comment: "Multiple Major Modes", more accurately. MuMaMo *is* supplied as part of nXhtml, but I would be extremely surprised if it could not be used separately from nxhtml-mode.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what are you looking for :

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PhpMode#toc8

You probably want to adapt it to fit your need

Comment: I don't want to bind mode change to a keypress, I want to change modes automatically within a buffer, so tags can act as triggers. But thanks anyway... =)